# Ajuda com python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Bom dia,
Tem uma coluna a mais mas não estou conseguindo perceber onde esta o erro.
segue o código:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
class arquivo:
     def __init__(self,master=None):
         self.widget1=Tk()
         self.widget1.title("Programa Transanches")
         self.tabela=ttk.Treeview(self.widget1,selectmode="browse",column=("column1","column2","column3","column4","column5"))
         self.tabela.column("column1", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#1", text="Numero Carga")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=0)
         self.tabela.column("column2", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#2", text="Cidades")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=1)
         self.tabela.column("column3", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#3", text="Estados")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=2)
         self.tabela.column("column4", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#4", text="Total de Peso")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=3)
         self.tabela.column("column5", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#5", text="Total de Volumes")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=4)
         self.widget1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, o erro que ocorre é que não aparece nada certo? Eis o pq:
vc tem que instanciar a classe pois ela foi construida mas não foi instanciada, outra questão apenas um conselho de boas práticas nomeie as classes com **LetraMausculaNasPrimeirasPalavras** ok? segue o código:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
class Arquivo:
     def __init__(self,master=None):
         self.widget1=Tk()
         self.widget1.title("Programa Transanches")
         self.tabela=ttk.Treeview(self.widget1,selectmode="browse",column=("column1","column2","column3","column4","column5"))
         self.tabela.column("column1", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#1", text="Numero Carga")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=0)
         self.tabela.column("column2", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#2", text="Cidades")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=1)
         self.tabela.column("column3", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#3", text="Estados")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=2)
         self.tabela.column("column4", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#4", text="Total de Peso")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=3)
         self.tabela.column("column5", width=200, minwidth=50, stretch=NO)
         self.tabela.heading("#5", text="Total de Volumes")
         self.tabela.grid(row=1, column=4)
         self.widget1.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Arquivo()
```

Comment: Obrigado, queridão pela força, descobrir o que faltava, esta faltando um cabeçalho